# Если картинка не найдена загрузить другую JS

Tags: javascript

Такая проблема, есть к примеру картинка в коде site.ru/img/супер пупер картинка.png

если на сайте вывожу и на сервере её не оказывается то отбавляем одно слово site.ru/img/супер пупер.png далее и так далее. в итоге если последнего слова не оказывается site.ru/img/супер.png то загружаем первую букву атрибута alt и вставляем див с ним в родителя, а картинку удаляем.

вот у меня набросок:

```js
   $("li .poster img").on('error', function() {
            var e = $(this);
            var b = e.parent().parent().text();
            var n = 1;
            reloadimage(e, b, n);
        });

function reloadimage(e, b, n) {
            var imgthis = e;
            var str = b;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                var id = str.lastIndexOf(' ');
                str = str.substring(0, id);
            }

            $(imgthis).attr('src', '/images/' + encodeURIComponent(str) + '.png').on('error', function() {
                if (str.split(" ").length == 1) {
  imgthis.parent().prepend('<div class="postertext">' + b.substr(0, 1) + '</div>');
                    imgthis.remove();
                } else {
                    n++;
                    reloadimage(e, b, n);
                }
            });
        }
```

хочу сделать универсальной мне для разных блоков надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вроде работает..

```js
$("li .poster img").bind('error', bindimgerr);

function bindimgerr() {
  var e = $(this),
    b = decodeURIComponent(e.attr('src').replace('http://hungry-bags.ru/shop/upload/', ''));
  if (b.split(" ").length > 1) {
    reloadimage(e, b);
  } else {
    e.parent().prepend('<div class="logotext">' + b.substr(0, 1) + '</div>');
    e.remove();
  }
}


function reloadimage(e, b) {
  var n = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var id1 = b.lastIndexOf(' ');
    b = b.substring(0, id1);
  }
  e.unbind('error');
  e.attr('src', 'http://hungry-bags.ru/shop/upload/' + encodeURIComponent(b) + '.jpg').on('error', function() {
    if (b.split(" ").length == 1) {
      e.parent().prepend('<div class="logotext">' + b.substr(0, 1) + '</div>');
      e.remove();
    } else {
      n++;
      reloadimage(e, b, n);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.poster img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.logotext {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="poster">
<img src="http://hungry-bags.ru/shop/upload/259937 эту картинку найдёт, она есть на сервере раз два три.jpg">
</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="poster">
<img src="http://hungry-bags.ru/shop/upload/хэхэхэй эту картинку не найдёт раз два три.jpg">
</span>
  </li>

</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

на любой нужный блок вешаю бинд и работает вроде)
может кто что поправит для красоты кода

Answer (score 4):

```js
function bubble_search(){
  const url = this.src.split('/');
  const name = url.pop();
  url.pop();
  url.push(name);
  this.src = url.join('/');
  console.log(this.src);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  const img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  img.onerror = bubble_search;
  img.src = img.src;
}, 1111);
```

```html
<img src = 'http://www.darkside.ru/band/825/band/825/band/825/band/825/n48793.jpg' />
```

Comment: что то не работает... он папки убирает.. на пробел пробовал менять не катит.. хотелось от названия файла отнимать последнее слово, если их несколько..